# export to excel from sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, export-to-excel

I am trying to export to excel from the following query. The following query doesn't work. Please let me know. I appreciate any help.

```
   INSERT INTO OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=c:\test.xls;','
    select distinct a.a_name, b.b_name, 
    CASE WHEN a.rights  = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS rights 
    FROM TABLE_A a 
    JOIN TABLE_B b ON a.a_id = b.a_id')
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086880/t-sql-export-to-new-excel-file/9086889#9086889

Comment: I am getting the following error message. OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be used for distributed queries

Comment: run this `sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO`

Comment: I was able copy and paste into Excel using sql server management studio.Thanks JonH.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Export Import Wizard in SSMS.

1. Right-click on the database which your query is using
2. Choose TASKS from the context menu which opens after right-clicking
3. Choose EXPORT DATA from menu
4. SQL Server Import and Export window will open.
5. In the wizard select your data source and where to export the data.
6. Enjoy!

Additional info/ tutorial can be found here
Please check http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-export-to-excel-using-import-export-wizard.aspx

Comment: All i get are unknown type errors. I even edited all of the mappings... :(