# Export query result to excel or csv on SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I wish to schedule the query result export to the excel sheet on SQL server. Is it possible to do that?

The query should create a new CSV or excel file and dump all the data from the query in to the sheet.

I tried

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=c:\contact.xls;',
'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
select * from temp1
```

But it requires the file to be present already.Can some one help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to create an EXCEL file in advance and want to export data to it, use

```
EXEC sp_makewebtask 
@outputfile = 'd:\testing.xls', 
@query = 'Select * from Database_name..SQLServerTable', 
@colheaders =1, 
@FixedFont=0,@lastupdated=0,@resultstitle='Testing details'
```

Possible Duplicate of 
[T-SQL: Export to new Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086880/t-sql-export-to-new-excel-file/9086889#9086889)

Comment: .i Get the error proc sp_makewebtask not found with the this moethod and with the previous approach I get " Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)"."

Answer (score 0):

Use Export/Import Wizard. 
Source: SQL server
Destination: Excel

You may need to indicate the name of Excel sheet and its location in folder structure.

I am showing only one step of the Wizard here:

[image]