# How to export SQL queries to Excel where the Excel file does not yet exists?

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I did an intensive search and could not seem to find an answer.

I want to export SQL queries to Excel and return it (the excel) to the client application or to my web-service. (think about a similar concept like `FOR XML` but instead return binary Excel data)

I tested this (after a long struggle) and it finally works fine:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\1.xls;', 
'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') 
SELECT TOP 5 ID, ItemName FROM dbo.MyItems
```

And return it to the clients:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'D:\1.xls', SINGLE_BLOB) rs
```

BUT, The file `D:\1.xls` must **exists** already in advanced. 
I have read this accepted answer: [T-SQL: Export to new Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9086889/3906993)

> 4 If you dont want to create an EXCEL file in advance and want to
>   export data to it, use `EXEC sp_makewebtask`

`sp_makewebtask` is deprecated.

Is there a way I could do this task without having an already existing file? or to at least dynamically create a suitable file before the export? or even better: *not use any files at all*?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-excel-workbench/

Comment: SSIS comes handy in such places. data can be put up on excel on the go.

Comment: @PrabhatG, can you please provide an example?

Comment: What is the original reason for using the Excel file? If you're looking for a method that doesn't use files this is *way* easier

Comment: @Rominus, I want to export SQL queries to Excel file and return it (the excel) to the client in my client application, instead of generating the Excel on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to do something like this before your call :

```
xp_cmdshell "echo . > D:\1.xls"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the purpose of your code is to move the top 5 Item Names to another table?  If that's the case all you need is `into`

```
SELECT TOP 5 ID, ItemName 
INTO dbo.Othertable
FROM dbo.MyItems
```

Comment: The TOP 5 was just an example. I want to export SQL queries to Excel file and return it (the excel) to the client in my client application, instead of generating the Excel on the client side.