# Want to get data fetched by Stored Procedure to excel file(sheetwise)

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

We have one stored procedure which has different input parameters and it is fetching data from multiple tables.

Also we have on excel template with multiple sheet. we want to insert data into excel sheet by creating different queries.
Does anybody tried that before?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to achieve this. When you want to write a program using .Net (what I expect from your tags), I can recommend [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus).

Comment: Currently i want to make everything in sql job

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086880/t-sql-export-to-new-excel-file) has the right answer for you...